# ASP.NET WebService Override SOAP Response

Tags: web-services, soap, asp.net-2.0

How do you override the SOAP response object from an ASP.NET Web Service before the service finishes sending it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement a [SoapExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soapextension.aspx). That's the only way I know of.